# maven-android-sdk-deployer not working due to missing v7\appcompat directory

Tags: android, google-maps, maven, maven-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to install Google Maps v2 libraries into my local Maven repository using [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) according to the manual on that page.

When I run `mvn install -P 4.1`, I get following error:

```
[INFO] C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras
\android\support\v7\appcompat\AndroidManifest.xml: error: Unable to open file fo
r read: No such file or directory
```

There is actually no `appcompat` directory in `C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\extras\android\support\v7`.

I suppose that I need to install some packag using the *Android SDK Manager*.

Which package (name, version) should I install in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for that command to work, it is necessary to install all "Extras" in the Android SDK manager.

[image: Android SDK Manager]